# Store previous value and check against the new value

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am currently trying to store previous value of a `Textbox` and compare it with a new value when `ontextchanged`. However, the problem now is that, whenever i try to store the previous value for comparing, the value is `null`.

Is there a way to store previous value?

Here's the code that I've tried. Assuming `tbDesc` have a old value of `Hello World`, and I edit the textbox with `Hello`

ASPX

```
public string oldvalue = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  oldvalue = tbDesc.Text;
}

protected void tbDesc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string newvalue = tbDesc.Text;

        if (newvalue != oldvalue)
       {
        tbDesc.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
       }
        else
      {
        tbDesc.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: because you set old value only in Page Load. you should set old value at end of TextChanged event. or use OnBlur event so old value is only set when textbox focus is removed.

Comment: There is also a better method. use timer. when user stopped typing after say 3 seconds then set old value.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary the thing is, on page load, i set the old value, however in the textchanged event, the old value is null.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I want to retain the old value and not change it.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET WebForms, a new instance of the page class is created for each request. This is the reason why the approach with a field in the class won't work. The field is initialized every time, the class is created. A static field does not solve this, because its contents are shared among all users.

In addition, you reset the value in Page_Load on every request. So this code should be removed.

In order to solve this, you need to add some [state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) to your page. As the scope is the page level, you could store the old value in ViewState. This way, the old value is transferred to the client and sent back to the server in a postback.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) shows an overview of ViewState.

The following sample shows how you can use ViewState to store the value across requests:

```
private string OldValue
{
    get
    {
        var viewStateVal = ViewState["OldValue"] as string;
        if (viewStateVal == null)
            return string.Empty;
        return viewStateVal;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["OldValue"] = value;
    }
}

protected void tbDesc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string newvalue = tbDesc.Text;
  if (newvalue != OldValue)
  {
      tbDesc.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      OldValue = newvalue;
  }
  else
      tbDesc.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

In some cases, ViewState might be disabled (e.g. to reduce the size of the page to save some bandwidth). In this case, using a Cookie would be an alternative.